# Schengen Visa as Seafarer

Tags: schengen-visas

I have a valid schengen visa, type C with multiple entry. I applied it as a seafarer for the purpose of joining the ship. My question is that, can I use it to visit a friend in schengen area? I am already home.

Comment: Does your visa reflect any restrictions?

Comment: Do you mean visiting friends on the way to the ship? Does your company pay for the trips and hotels? If it is so, maybe it is not 100% legal, but people do such visits [short visit, not overnight] (ships have often delays, or you need to change port). But I would not do a visit on first contract.

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazzi, I already used the visa when I joined the ship and now I am already home. I am asking if its possible to go in a schengen area again not with the same purpose for a second trip.

Answer (score 3):

[Mark Johnson](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/95267/mark-johnson)'s answer is incorrect on several counts, many of which were noted in the comments, which were moved to a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100755/discussion-on-answer-by-mark-johnson-schengen-visa-as-seafarer).

A similar question attracted a [much better answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/169396/19400) from [Relaxed](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6669/relaxed).  Essentially, such a visit should be possible with this visa, but the situation is not entirely clear.  Anyone who uses a Schengen visa for a purpose other than that for which it was granted should be prepared to answer questions at the border about the purpose of the visit and means of support.

Answer (score 1):

No, since a visa issued for a seafarer is basically a **transit** visa, using it as a **visitor's** visa is not possible.

Based on the new information supplied, you have been issued a Netherlands **visitor's visa** (BNL 2), so you can use this to visit your friend.

So it will depend on how the visa was issued.

If you also applied for a **visitor's** option, which, if granted, is stated on the visa, then there is no problem

- for this a health insurance must exist that would cover a private visit, which *may* not be covered by a seamans health insurance

If not, you should adhere strictly to the issued conditions.

In the legal text you will often find the following text:

> in case of seafarers known for **their integrity and reliability** (i.e. *correct use of previously issued visas*)

as part of the preconditions for the issuing of a multiple entry visa.
This is especially true in cases where the visa is issued at the **external border**.

---

**Belgium, Netherlands and Luxembourg**

> BNL 1 : visa issued following authorisation by the central authorities.
>
> BNL 2: visa issued ex officio (the visa was issued by the consulate without referring to central authority).

- both of these are standard **visitor's** visas

**Netherlands only**

- the alien's number

The Netherlands does not use the standard C-Sticker for transit Visas

- [C-Visa 2011](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/NLD-CO-01004/index.html)

---

Netherlands Sticker for transit visa:

- [visa to return to the Netherlands (and transit through the Schengen area)](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/NLD-CO-02001/index.html)

[image]

---

> **5.2.1 Non-exhaustive list of supporting documents regarding the purpose of the journey, the accommodation and the assessment of the applicant’s intention to leave the territory
> of the Member States that may be requested by the consulate**
> A. DOCUMENTATION RELATING TO THE PURPOSE OF THE JOURNEY
> **g) seafarers**

- Seaman's book
- Covering letter from recruiting company stating the name and the rank of the seafarer
- Vessel's name, vessel's arrival date in port and the date of the seafarer's joining of the vessel

> **Recommended best practice for seafarers**: It is not always possible to determine in which Member State a seafarer will **start his transit** because the shipping companies who employ them often do not know in advance on which ship going to which Member State a seafarer is to embark. It is therefore recommended that Article 5 (2) (b) of the Visa Code be applied in a flexible manner in case of seafarers known for their integrity and reliability (i.e. correct use of previously issued visas): the consulate of either of the Member States where the transit could possibly start should deal with the visa application.

---

**Sources**:

- [Visa Code 2016-03-23 M4, 2018 C1](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CONSLEG:2009R0810:20160412:EN:PDF)

  - [Operational Instructions, 2019-05-14](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/docs/20140709_visa_code_handbook_consolidated_en.pdf)
- [Annex 22 National entries in the "comments" section of the visa sticker](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/e-library/documents/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/docs/visa_sticker_comments_section_en.pdf)
- [PRADO - Public Register of Authentic travel and identity Documents Online](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/prado-start-page.html)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100755/discussion-on-answer-by-mark-johnson-schengen-visa-as-seafarer).

Comment: (-1) For reference, since most of the discussion has unfortunately been moved to a comment thread: There are serious issues with this answer, most of which is irrrelevant or baseless. The notion of a separate transit visa (outside of **airport** transit visa) has been removed from Schengen rules over a decade ago and is legally dubious.